# Can You Embed an AND Statement Within an OR Statement?

Tags: excel

Alright, so I have an idea, but I am not sure if there is a way to accomplish this. Starting with this equation:

=IF(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,{"I","A","X","R","K","E","AL","FFSL","ADM*"})))=10),"80 Hours","Error")

I would like to embed an AND statement within the same IF statement, if that is at all possible. For instance, the equation above checks all the possible 8 hours shifts. If there are 10 of them then the employee is schedule to work 80 hours. I next need to check for a combination of 4 ten hour shifts and 5 eight hour shifts. I then need to continue checking other possible combinations that would get the employee to 80 hours.

I know this equation below does not work, but this is what I am trying to do something similar to.

=IF(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,{"I","A","X","R","K","E","AL","FFSL","ADM*"})))=10,(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,{"R-10","I-10","X-10","A-10"})))=4,AND(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,{"I","A","X","R","K","E","AL","FFSL","ADM*"})))=5),"80 Hours","Error")

Essentially I am trying to embed an AND statement within the original OR statement. Not sure if that is even allowed. I am saying something like this:

IF 1 OR (2 AND 3) OR (3 AND 4), etc...

[image: Test Schedule]

Comment: You can nest `AND()` within `OR()`, but it will not work with an array formula.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Do you have any ideas of how I could solve this problem?

Comment: It is definiatly possible to imbed the AND, ie `=IF(OR(A2=1,AND(A2=2,B2=3),AND(A2=5,B2=3)),1,0)`

Comment: Can you please explain the structure of the data and what you are trying to accomplish? It is difficult to glean that from your question.

Comment: I have added an image of an example excel file. I am searching each row to make sure the number of shifts add up to 80 hours. The boxes with just letters are eight hour shifts and the ones with -10 are ten hour shifts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this?

=IF(OR(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,{"I","A","X","R","K","E","AL","FFSL","ADM*"})))=10, 
AND(ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,{"R-10","I-10","X-10","A-10"})))=4, ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(B7:O7,"I","A","X","R","K","E","AL","FFSL","ADM*"})))=5)) ,"80 Hours","Error")

Comment: Ah, I just had to add the "{" back in and it worked! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In excel `AND` and `OR` are functions, not operators. So `IF 1 OR (2 AND 3) OR (3 AND 4)..` will translate to

```
IF( OR(1, AND(2, 3), AND(3,4)) , <true_statement>, <false_statement>)
```

Comment: Thanks, Eugene. I believe that is how Minh changed the equation above, so we are on the right track, but something is still now quite right...

Comment: Got it figured out. Was just missing a "{". Thanks for the help!